# Expected identifier or something?

Tags: c, windows

I have typed code posted below in DEV C++, which is an updated version, the Orwell one. It gave me some errors and I would like you to help me with them :) Most of the errors are already been fixed by me, but some of them I just cant explain. I am just trying to do simple MS app program.

Compiler gives me this error:

> **LINE 53**  *[Error] expected identifier or '(' before '{' token*

The code:

```
# include <windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WinMain (HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
    {

        static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("HelloWin");
        HWND                    hwnd;
        MSG                     msg;
        WNDCLASS                wndclass;
        wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW| CS_VREDRAW;
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
        wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        wndclass.hInstance     = hinstance;
        wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH);
        wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
        wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

        if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
        {
            MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("XXCXCXCXCX"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
            return     (0);
         }     

        hwnd  = CreateWindow    (szAppName,
                                TEXT("FRFRFRFRF"),
                                WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                hinstance,
                                NULL);
        ShowWindow  (hwnd, iCmdShow);
        UpdateWindow (hwnd);

        while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage (& msg);
                DispatchMessage  (& msg);
            }   /* END while*/
            return (msg.wParam);

    }           /* END WinMain () */


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lparam);
  { ("**this is line 53**")




                HDC                   hdc;
                PAINTSTRUCT           ps;
                RECT                  rect;


                switch (message)

                {

                    case        WM_CREATE:
                                PlaySound("FRFRFRZZZZZ.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME|SND-ASIAC
                                return (0);

                    case        WM_PAINT:
                                hdc = BeginPaint (hwnd, &ps);
                                GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);
                                DrawText (hdc, TEXT ("HZHZHZHZ!"), -1, &, DT_SINGLELINE|DT-CENTER|DT_VCENT;
                                EndPoint (hwnd, &ps);
                                return (0);

                    case        WM_DESTROY;
                                PostQuitMessage (0);
                                return (0);

                }  

                return      (DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam));

    }
```

Happy new year, and it's the rest of the code okay?

Comment: Which line is line 53? You have line numbers in your editor. You could at least put a comment in the code to indicate where the error is happening.

Comment: Based on the line and the fact that something before a { is the problem, it shouldn't be hard to spot.

Comment: So sorry that i havent marketed 53 line. It is corrected now.

Comment: Look at `DrawText (hdc, ..., -1, &, DT_...)`. That line contains three different errors.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the semicolon `;` at:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lparam);
```

Edited For clarity.

You have a declaration at the beginning that looks like the following

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); // <-- OK
```

Later you have the actual function

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lparam); // <--Error. Delete ';'
{ ("**this is line 53**")
:
}
```

Comment: If i do that i get in line 52: [Error] parameter name omitted

Comment: @Janac, Well, omitting the parameter name is legal C++, which you tagged this question as. Anyway, now that we've established this is C, just give it a name.

Comment: I didnt know that C++ is completely different language. It is C yes.

Comment: @Janac Harsh as it may sound: Learn programming. Pasting random source code off the web into some IDE will not get you anywhere. Lee provided the correct answer to your question. You should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In your callback function,when you call PlaySound and DrawText functions,missing '()' and ')' .Function parameters should be placed in ( ).
By the way,when the message is WM_PAINT,if you want to call EndPaint rather than EndPoint.

Comment: Thats fixed now, but what to do with line 53?